# Column result doesn't as be expected

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

Here i have query to join two table and merge it into one result by using this query

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_barang RIGHT JOIN tb_jenis ON tb_barang.kd_jenis = tb_jenis.kd_jenis ";
```

And here is my table structures for both of tables

Table "tb_barang"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OpeC.png

And Table "tb_jenis"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhLty.png

I was expecting the output like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhtHx.png

However, when I take column "jenis", java throw exception into it because either out of range or column not found.

Then i check whether the column is exist or not using :

```java
ResultSet resTabel = new mysqlDriver().getKolomBarangList();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resTabel.getMetaData();
            int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            if (resTabel.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Col(" + i + ") '" + metaData.getColumnName(i) + "' value:" + resTabel.getString(i));
    }
```

The output:

```
Col(1) 'kd_barang' value:BAR0000
Col(2) 'nama_barang' value:A
Col(3) 'kd_jenis' value:J_1
Col(4) 'jumlah_barang' value:1
Col(5) 'harga_satuan' value:1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 35 seconds)
```

How to achieve this? Thanks for response

Comment: *when I take column "jenis"*: as your output shows, there is indeed no such column. There is one named "kd_jenis", though.

Comment: what happens when you call `resultSet.getString("kd_jenis")` ?

Comment: Why do you expect that expected result? Both rows match. What is that `item 1`?

Comment: indeed @JBNizet , but i thought "jenis" column also included into the results.

Comment: @guleryuz . return to "J_1". when i switch to "jenis", it throw "column "jenis" not found

Comment: @forpas i was expecting like the "kd_jenis" return as "Pakan Ayam". ignore item 1, just for debugging purposes

Comment: There is a column named `jenis` in table `tb_jenis` and it should be included in the results.

Comment: Post the results you get.

Comment: how do i can achive that @forpas ?

Comment: I don't see in your code that you execute the query and get results. You are getting meta data for what? What is `getKolomBarangList()`?

Comment: thanks @forpas . i was miss type the method name, and i get result as i expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, i was miss type the method name thanks to @forpas. the `getKolomBarangList()` refer to field name of table `tb_barang` and not executing "JOIN" clauses

```java
protected ResultSet getBarangList()throws SQLException, NullPointerException, ClassNotFoundException{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_barang RIGHT JOIN tb_jenis ON tb_barang.kd_jenis = tb_jenis.kd_jenis ";
        if(resForListBarang == null){
            resForListBarang = alwaysDoResultSet(query);
        }
        return resForListBarang;
    }

    protected ResultSet getKolomBarangList() throws SQLException, Exception{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_barang";
        if(getBarangKolom == null){
            getBarangKolom = alwaysDoResultSet(query);
        }
        return getBarangKolom;
    }
```

And the output for `getBarangList()` was expected as the final result

```
Col(1) 'kd_barang' value:BAR0000
Col(2) 'nama_barang' value:A
Col(3) 'kd_jenis' value:J_1
Col(4) 'jumlah_barang' value:1
Col(5) 'harga_satuan' value:1
Col(6) 'kd_jenis' value:J_1
Col(7) 'jenis' value:Pakan Hewan
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)
```

Thanks to anyone who helping me out :)